# Star Traders issues on Intel Mac?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, macos, star-traders-frontiers

I recently got the Steam discount bundle of deep games, that includes Wildermyth, Vagrus, and Star Traders: Frontiers. I'm loving Wildermyth (beautiful story-focused RPG) and Vagrus (incredible desert trader RPG), but I can't get Star Traders to work on an Intel Mac. It crashes during character creation. I think there's a basic graphics issue with games on Intel-based Macs -- I've seen patches in other games to fix it -- so any tips, tricks, or news for Star Trader?

If I can't get it to work, I might ask for a refund, but since it's a part of a bundle, I imagine that might refund the other two games as well, and I really don't want to do that. (For that matter, if you refund something on sale, I assume you can't then buy the pieces on sale, right?)

Comment: Yes, you can still buy the parts of a bundle or even a single game that you've refunded previously. Just make sure there's no version differences that could create issues and cause another refund request "too soon" and be considered abuse.